# Need help, JavaScript – how to remove a single value from a <style> block

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating a tool for people with disabilities to help them access the site. One of the many functions the tool has is to change colour: text, headings, background.

**What have I now?**
When a user changes colour tool search for elements:

```
for(let i = 0, elements = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'strong']; i < elements.length; i++) {
    documeny.querySelector(elements[i]).style.color = color;
}
```

But I know it will be slow if there are a lot of elements with a specific tag on the page. I want to dynamically create a  block and save the css properties.

Note: E.g. h1 will have more than one css property, e.g. color and letter-spacing.

**What I want to do?**
I want to create e.g.

```
<style>
    h1 {
        color: #000;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    }
</style>
```

And when the user removes the letter spacing property, it removes it from the  block and leaves the colour.

**How I see it and what I need?**
I will create one  block for all CSS changes, and then add to this block properties:

```
let c = document.createDocumentFragment();
let e = document.createElement("style");
e.id = 'toolbox-styles';
c.appendChild(e);
document.head.appendChild(c);

// Then
document.getElementById('toolbox-styles').innerCSS.h1.letterSpacing = ''; // I know it doesn't exist, but It's more less what I think i need)
```

**Where I need help?**
I don't know how:

1. Add new CSS for e.g. h1 to existing one (in the block);
2. Remove only one property from e.g. h1 CSS
3. Create new css for e.g. h2 in  block with css for h1:

   ```
   <style>
       h1 {
           letter-spacing: 0.5px;
           color: red;
       }
       h2 { // Another element
           color: blue;
       }
   </style>
   ```

Comment: I think it has .innerHTML and .innerText like any other tag

Comment: And how to 1. find the value using an efficient code, 2. append element after last {} block, 3. remove whole {} block and leave others?

Comment: Check out https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can use css variables to modify styling changes to your code with js.
You have `getPropertyValue` and `setProperty` to use for this purpose.

Just add some variables in your stylesheet to `:root` and modify it with `setProperty`.

Please see these Links for further infos:

[CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty)

[CSSStyleDeclaration.getPropertyValue()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue)

```js
// Get the root element
var r = document.querySelector(':root');


// Create a function for setting a variable value
function setColor() {
  // Set the value of variable --blue to another value (in this case "lightblue")
  r.style.setProperty('--blue', 'lightblue');
}
```

```css
:root {
  --blue: #1e90ff;
  --white: #ffffff; 
}

body {
  background-color: var(--blue);
}

h2 {
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--blue);
}

.container {
  color: var(--blue);
  background-color: var(--white);
  padding: 15px;
}

.container button  {
  background-color: var(--white);
  color: var(--blue);
  border: 1px solid var(--blue);
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>  
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit.</p>
      <button>Yes</button>
      <button>No</button>
    </div>
    <br/>  
    <button type="button" onclick="setColor()">Change CSS Variables</button>
  </body>
</html>
```